# Sum by ID for many columns in a Python DataFrame using for loop and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe

name......  value .... marks ... points

vas.........   234   ......... 10   ........   16

raghu .. .. 324 ........   10  ........    12

vas  ........   200 ........   10   .........   12

sri  ..........   66  ..........   10   .........   52

naveen .. 76 .........    10     .......... 43

raghu.....   50  .........   10     .......... 12

raghu  .... 50  ........   10    ...........  23

prathu ... 100  ......  10  ...........    21

sri   .........  100  ......  10  ...........    54

sri   ..........  25   ......  10 ............     34

sri    .......... 25  ......   10    ...........  23

prathu ... 25 ......    10  ............    43

vasu  .....  125 ....   10  ............    23

naveen ... 50  ....   10  ............    53

Here name column is the ID and based on each name I need to sum up all the corresponding columns using groupby and for loop. I tried for one column using groupby but when I am trying for multiple columns i am failing.
the following step helped to sum for one column :

df[New_VALUE] = df.groupby(["name"])["value"].transform(sum)

But when trying for all the columns it is throwing different errors. I am new to Python.

Comment: Your code seems nice, `df['New_VALUE'] = df.groupby(["name"])["value"].transform(sum)`, can you add errors to your question?

Comment: When using for loop. I am getting 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Can you add all code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think loop is not necessary, only use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) + [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.join(df.groupby("name").transform(sum).add_prefix('sum_'))
print (df)
      name  value  marks  points  sum_value  sum_marks  sum_points
0      vas    234     10      16        434         20          28
1    raghu    324     10      12        424         30          47
2      vas    200     10      12        434         20          28
3      sri     66     10      52        216         40         163
4   naveen     76     10      43        126         20          96
5    raghu     50     10      12        424         30          47
6    raghu     50     10      23        424         30          47
7   prathu    100     10      21        125         20          64
8      sri    100     10      54        216         40         163
9      sri     25     10      34        216         40         163
10     sri     25     10      23        216         40         163
11  prathu     25     10      43        125         20          64
12    vasu    125     10      23        125         10          23
13  naveen     50     10      53        126         20          96
```

But if need it for another processing:

```
for c in df.columns[1:]:
    df['sum_{}'.format(c)] = df.groupby("name")[c].transform(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `agg` to sum all the rows for all columns

```
df = df.groupby('name').agg(sum)
```